# How can I stop the quick settings from being opened?

Tags: android

So I want to make an app that runs in a kiosk mode. This is an enterprise app and this app does not need to be placed on the app store.

The tablets will not be rooted, so I cannot use an app that requires root.

I have successfully disabled home button (my app is a launcher), back button, recent apps, power button (I close system dialogs on focus changed).

How can I close the notification tray as it is opening? I have this code, but it does not work while the user is dragging.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        if (! hasFocus) {
            Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
            sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the official kiosk mode offered on Android 5.0+, rather than rolling all this yourself?

Comment: @CommonsWare  I am checking it now

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there a way to disable the exiting of this mode?

Comment: I thought that was part of the feature set: you can't leave a pinned app.

Comment: @CommonsWare you can exit by pressing back and recents together, and there doesn't seem to be a way to block that

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by trying every 50ms to close the system dialogs while I don't have focus:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(!hasFocus && isKioskModeActive) {
        t = new Thread(() -> {
            while (!hasWindowFocus() && isKioskModeActive) {
                // Close every kind of system dialog
                Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
                sendBroadcast(closeDialog);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Thread interrupted: 'Kiosk Close system dialog'");
                }

            }
            t = null;
        });

        t.start();
    }
}
```